# How can I set up "test" environments in Python

Tags: python

Is there a way to execute a file but still be able to call the variables? This would help immensely in learning Python, since I could set up many different "practice" scripts and then use the console to try and modify the code to see what happens.

I think the technical question would be "How can I populate a namespace in Python in Eclipse and leave it open to interactions in the console?

Below is a screenshot showing what I'm trying to do, define a (as 1) in the editor, and then press "ctrl-alt-enter" to run the file in the console, and then call the variable from the console.

[Screenshot of Eclipse]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExySo.png]

Comment: `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to add a debugging breakpoint at the end of code you are executing and inspect variables using a good editor.

In general, you should be able to run simple scripts right inside a python interpreter. Or online if you wish to: http://www.datamech.com/devan/trypython/trypython.py

Try setting up a REPL (read-eval-print) environment using your favorite editor. For instance, emacs has good support for doing such tasks.

Comment: In Eclipse in particular, setting a break point will allow you to inspect the variable values, as well as type in the Console to test things.  Just put something bogus like "print 'stop'" as the last line in your script, set the break point. You can play around as much as you want in the console while the debug is paused on the breakpoint.